# Self-loops in Graph may not display correctly or export correctly to PDF (due to BezierCurve problem)

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, export, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.2**

 Problem is due to a `BezierCurve` bug.

---

I don't understand why the following does not work:

```
Export["graph.pdf", Graph[{1 <-> 1, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
        EdgeStyle -> {Black}, VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> .05]]
```

It evaluates fine, but the resulting `PDF` only seems to show half the loop at vertex 1.

The problem seems to be with `EdgeShapeFunction`: it displays correctly in *Mathematica*, but does not export correctly to `PDF`

Comment: I should probably add that the problem seems to be with `EdgeShapeFunction`: it displays correctly in Mathematica, but does not export correctly to PDF.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug to Wolfram Technical Support. A support case with the identification [CASE:1762814] was created.

Comment: @rhermans and Steve, can either of you (or anyone else reading) confirm that this bug existed in 10.0.0?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sorry no, I don't have 10.0.0 any more, and Wolfram Technical Support didn't comment further when they replied. 'Replicated and an incident report was forwarded to developers', was pretty much all they said.

Comment: The bug is still present in M10.2

Comment: I can reproduce this bug up through 11.1.1.  In 11.2, it is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem (Win7 64, M10.0.1). Same problem if you try with *PDF* or *EPS* format.

[image: Graph with bug]

When actually your graph should look like this

```
Graph[{1 <-> 1, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line",  EdgeStyle -> {Black}, VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> .05]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

It looks like this is a bug, but there is an easy way around if you can afford to have a raster image instead of a vector. The graph can be transformed into a bitmap using [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html)

```
Export["graph.pdf", 
 Rasterize[
  Graph[{1 <-> 1, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
   EdgeStyle -> {Black}, VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> .05], 
  ImageSize -> 2^10]]
```

[image: Graph rasterized]

Until this is fixed if you need vector format, you can use *SVG*, which works fine.

**EDIT:**

or, you can remove the option `EdgeShapeFunction->"Line"` as pointed out by @Steve_D, i.e yourself. Still, this is a bug.

[image]

Comment: You can actually fix the problem by removing the `EdgeShapeFunction->"Line"`.

Comment: On my system (OS X 10.10.4), it doesn't even display correctly in the notebook, so rasterization doesn't help either.  I traced the problem back to a `BezierCurve` bug.

Answer (score 6):

On my system (OS X 10.10.4) it doesn't even display correctly on-screen.  This means that rasterization doesn't help.

I can confirm the problem in 10.0.2, 10.1.0 and 10.2.0.  The problem doesn't exist in 9.0.1.

[image]

**We can trace back this problem to a `BezierCurve` bug.**

```
gr = 
  Show@Graph[{1 <-> 1, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
    EdgeStyle -> {Black}, VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> .05];

bc = First@Cases[gr, _BezierCurve, Infinity]
(* BezierCurve[{{1., 0.}, {1.08848, 0.190784}, {1.28736, 0.24718}, {1.41453, 0.188223}, {1.41453, -0.188223}, {1.28736, -0.24718}, {1.08848, -0.190784}, {1., 0.}}, SplineDegree -> 7] *)

Graphics[{bc, Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts], Black, Dashed, Line[pts]}]
```

Note that only half of the curve is displayed.  This only happens with `SplineDegree -> 7` in this case.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`BezierFunction` doesn't suffer from the same problem:

```
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> 7][t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]